# How to parse URL parameters in VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to parse parameters in a URL in VBA.  For example:

https://www.google.com/webhp?q=vba+url+parameters&utf_source=stackoverflow

I'm looking to get something like a hash table with q mapping to 'vba+url+parameters' and utf_source mapping to 'stackoverflow'.

Is there an existing data structure/function for this?  Or will I need to build something to parse it myself?  I've looked through the MSHTML library and can't find anything obvious, and the MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement.href attribute just returns a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164502%28v=office.10%29.aspx) object.

You can extract everything to the right of the question mark, and add the values to a dictionary.

Comment: Of course that still requires the OP to parse the string himself.  But I agree Dictionary is the right data structure to store the results.

Comment: `Split(Split(inputURL,"?")(1),"&")` will give you an array of "name=value"

Comment: For those not familiar with the Dictionary object, you need to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".  I ended up using this as my answer and coding up a quick and dirty url parser.  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really answer Kevin's question. He knows he needs something *like* a hash map, such as a Dictionary, but he's asking for a method of geting that data structure. mrwolfe02's answer is far more practical. @KevinPope, would you mind sharing your URL parser and posting it as an answer?

Comment: @StockB - Sorry, this code was written for a position at a former company, so I no longer have access to the code.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a general purpose Parse function that works with connection strings, URLs, and other key-value types of strings.  Here's how it works:

```
Sub TestParse()
Dim s As String

    s = "https://www.google.com/webhp?q=vba+url+parameters&utf_source=stackoverflow"
    Debug.Print Parse(s, "q", vbString, "=", "&")
    Debug.Print Parse(s, "utf_source", vbString, "=", "&")

End Sub
```

outputs:

```
vba+url+parameters
stackoverflow
```

And here's the function:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : Parse
' DateTime  : 7/16/2009 11:32
' Author    : Mike
' Purpose   : Parse a string of keys and values (such as a connection string) and return
'               the value of a specific key.
' Usage     - Use to pass multiple arguments to forms via OpenArgs in MS Access
'           - Keep multiple arguments in the Tag property of forms and controls.
'           - Use to parse a user-entered search string.
' Notes     - Defaults to using connection string formatted key-value pairs.
'           - Specifying a ReturnType guarantees the type of the result and allows the
'               function to be safely called in certain situations.
'  7/23/09  : Modified to allow the use of a literal space as a delimiter while allowing
'               values to have spaces as well. 
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Function Parse(Txt As Variant, Key As String, _
               Optional ReturnType As VbVarType = vbVariant, _
               Optional AssignChar As String = "=", _
               Optional Delimiter As String = ";") As Variant    
Dim StartPos As Integer, EndPos As Integer, Result As Variant
    Result = Null
    If IsNull(Txt) Then
        Parse = Null
    ElseIf Len(Key) = 0 Then
        EndPos = InStr(Txt, AssignChar)
        If EndPos = 0 Then
            Result = Trim(Txt)
        Else
            If InStrRev(Txt, " ", EndPos) = EndPos - 1 Then
                EndPos = InStrRev(Txt, Delimiter, EndPos - 2)
            Else
                EndPos = InStrRev(Txt, Delimiter, EndPos)
            End If
            Result = Trim(Left(Txt, EndPos))
        End If
    Else
        StartPos = InStr(Txt, Key & AssignChar)
        'Allow for space between Key and Assignment Character
        If StartPos = 0 Then
            StartPos = InStr(Txt, Key & " " & AssignChar)
            If StartPos > 0 Then StartPos = StartPos + Len(Key & " " & AssignChar)
        Else
            StartPos = StartPos + Len(Key & AssignChar)
        End If
        If StartPos = 0 Then
            Parse = Null
        Else
            EndPos = InStr(StartPos, Txt, AssignChar)
            If EndPos = 0 Then
                If Right(Txt, Len(Delimiter)) = Delimiter Then
                    Result = Trim(Mid(Txt, StartPos, _
                                      Len(Txt) - Len(Delimiter) - StartPos + 1))
                Else
                    Result = Trim(Mid(Txt, StartPos))
                End If
            Else
                If InStrRev(Txt, Delimiter, EndPos) = EndPos - 1 Then
                    EndPos = InStrRev(Txt, Delimiter, EndPos - 2)
                Else
                    EndPos = InStrRev(Txt, Delimiter, EndPos)
                End If
                If EndPos < StartPos Then
                    Result = Trim(Mid(Txt, StartPos))
                Else
                    Result = Trim(Mid(Txt, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos))
                End If
            End If

        End If
    End If
    Select Case ReturnType
    Case vbBoolean
        If IsNull(Result) Or Len(Result) = 0 Or Result = "False" Then
            Parse = False
        Else
            Parse = True
            If IsNumeric(Result) Then
                If Val(Result) = 0 Then Parse = False
            End If
        End If

    Case vbCurrency, vbDecimal, vbDouble, vbInteger, vbLong, vbSingle
        If IsNumeric(Result) Then
            Select Case ReturnType
            Case vbCurrency: Parse = CCur(Result)
            Case vbDecimal: Parse = CDec(Result)
            Case vbDouble: Parse = CDbl(Result)
            Case vbInteger: Parse = CInt(Result)
            Case vbLong: Parse = CLng(Result)
            Case vbSingle: Parse = CSng(Result)
            End Select
        Else
            Select Case ReturnType
            Case vbCurrency: Parse = CCur(0)
            Case vbDecimal: Parse = CDec(0)
            Case vbDouble: Parse = CDbl(0)
            Case vbInteger: Parse = CInt(0)
            Case vbLong: Parse = CLng(0)
            Case vbSingle: Parse = CSng(0)
            End Select
        End If

    Case vbDate
        If IsDate(Result) Then
            Parse = CDate(Result)
        ElseIf IsNull(Result) Then
            Parse = 0
        ElseIf IsDate(Replace(Result, "#", "")) Then
            Parse = CDate(Replace(Result, "#", ""))
        Else
            Parse = 0
        End If

    Case vbString
        Parse = Nz(Result, vbNullString)

    Case Else
        If IsNull(Txt) Then
            Parse = Null
        ElseIf Result = "True" Then
            Parse = True
        ElseIf Result = "False" Then
            Parse = False
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Result) Then
            Parse = Val(Result)
        Else
            Parse = Result
        End If
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: And in Access 2016! :-)